# How to make 'rails notes' raketask work also for code in Rails Engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I would like to use the `rails notes` command to list various annotation comments in a rails application which uses multiple rails engines.

Using either

```
rails notes:fixme
rails notes:custom ANNOTATION=FIXME
```

only yields the notes from the root server path (`/app`) but not adding notes from the engines code paths which reside in `components/engine_name` folders (`/components/myengine/app`).

Can i add the engines search-path somewhere so it is being picked up by this Raketask ?